# Changing user and installing ruby

Tags: ansible

My Ansible server is communicating as root user with agent but I need to install ruby as different user i.e deploy. So I am trying to switch the user to deploy using 'become' to install ruby but I am facing issue. Its seems that when i am trying to switch the user and running the command its unable to use .bashrc file of deploy user. Below is my YML file

```
---
- hosts: test1
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: adding node.js repository
    shell: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
  - name: adding yarn pubkey
    shell: curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  - name: adding yarn repo
    shell: echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
  - name: update cache
    apt: update_cache=true
  - name: install all the below list of packages
    apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=true
    with_items:
      - git-core
      - curl 
      - zlib1g-dev 
      - build-essential 
      - libssl-dev 
      - libreadline-dev 
      - libyaml-dev 
      - libsqlite3-dev 
      - sqlite3 
      - libxml2-dev 
      - libxslt1-dev 
      - libcurl4-openssl-dev 
      - software-properties-common 
      - libffi-dev 
      - nodejs 
      - yarn
  - name: change to deploy home directory
    shell: cd 
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: getting repo from git
    shell: git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: copy path
    shell: echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: copy eval
    shell: echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: execute shell
    shell: exec $SHELL
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: ruby repo
    shell: git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: copy paths
    shell: echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: shell execute
    shell: exec $SHELL
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: install ruby
    shell: rbenv install 2.4.4
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
  - name: set global
    shell: rbenv global 2.4.4
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
```

I am getting the below error:

```
TASK [install ruby] ***************
```

> fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "rbenv install
>   2.4.4", "delta": "0:00:00.003186", "end": "2018-09-25 15:43:23.224716", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start":
>   "2018-09-25 15:43:23.221530", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: rbenv: not
>   found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: 1: rbenv: not found"], "stdout":
>   "", "stdout_lines": []}

But when I am providing the path manually in command for rbenv its working fine. As shown below:

```
- name: install ruby
  shell: /home/deploy/.rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.4.4
  become: true
  become_user: deploy
```

Can you please tell me why its behaving like this?

I need to install bundler also using gem. I am switching to user 'deploy' but its going to check the root user directory instead of deploy user and giving error. Please refer the below YML part for gem and error:

```
  - name: install bundler
    shell: gem install bundler
    become: true
    become_user: deploy
```

Below is the error for bundler:

```
TASK [install bundler] *********
```

> fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "gem install
>   bundler", "delta": "0:00:02.396195", "end": "2018-09-25
>   16:21:18.703899", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start":
>   "2018-09-25 16:21:16.307704", "stderr": "ERROR:  While executing gem
>   ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)\n    You don't have write permissions
>   for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.", "stderr_lines": ["ERROR: 
>   While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)", "    You don't
>   have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory."],
>   "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Please help me to fix the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Please help me on above issue.

Answer (score 0):

That playbook does not do what you think it does, because every one of those tasks is *effectively* its own ssh connection. So, this:

```
- name: change to deploy home directory
  shell: cd 
  become: true
  become_user: deploy
- name: execute shell
  shell: exec $SHELL
```

... is equivalent to `ssh root@the-host "su deploy -c 'cd; exit'"; ssh root@the-host "su deploy -c 'exec $SHELL; exit'"` and so forth.

You'll very like also want to move all of those tasks that run as `deploy` into their own playbook or role, and include them with those `become: true` and `become: deploy` at the include or role level to keep from repeating that text all over the tasks.

But even if you don't do that, the shortest path to success is to collapse all 10 of those steps into just one `shell: |` block to rescue your sanity and reinforce that they all need to happen in the same shell session

```
- name: install ruby using rbenv
  become: true
  become_user: deploy
  shell: |
     set -e  # <-- stop running this script if something fails
     cd $HOME
     export ... # etc etc
  args:
    creates: /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/bin/ruby
```

Optionally including that `args: creates:` business will give ansible a fighting chance to skip that step if it has already provisioned `rbenv`. You will, of course, likely want to update that to guard the step in a way that is more relevant to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How we can run multiple commands with in single shell using shell module in single task? What will be syntax?

Comment: Which part of the explicitly quoted syntax in my answer does not work for you?